# Preserving FacesMessage after redirect for presentation through <h:message> in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, redirect, jsf-2

I have what I suppose is a common problem: some managed bean has an action which adds some messages to the context:

```
FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage("didn't work");
fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, fm);
return "some-outcome";
```

Then I map the outcome in `faces-config.xml` and configure it to

```
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>some-outcome</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/view.xhtml</to-view-id>
    <redirect/>
</navigation-case>
```

In `view.xhtml` I present the message:

```
<h:message globalsOnly="true" />
```

However, it does not work because the message is lost when the redirect is executed.

How would I solve it? I found this [amazing post](http://blog.kaiec.org/2009/03/01/message-handling-with-jsf-and-redirects/) explaining how to do it using a `PhaseListener` but I believe this situation is too common to have to be solved this way. Am I wrong? Should I create the `PhaseListener`? Or is there some other, standard solutions?

Comment: Where is the @BalusC answer?

Comment: Um.... can't read the code in the 'amazing post'.   Also can't find the @BalusC answer.

Comment: @JoshuaDavis I remember that BalusC has posted a good answer. Actually, I have marked this answer as *the* answer. I wonder what happened...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great answer from BalusC as usual!

I just want to add, when i used his code to set the keepMessages property, it was not set for the session, but only for this request (despite what it says in the Javadocs).

I put the following code in my header.xhtml
    `<c:set target="#{flash}" property="keepMessages" value="true" />`

Now it works on every page, without me having to set it every time i need it in the backing bean.
You need JSTL for this and dont forget to put the following in your xhtml header:
    `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"`

Comment: I think this is the link for BalusC's post: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/03/post-redirect-get-pattern.html

Answer (score 5):

**JSF 2.2**

**Into the bean:**

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Flash flash = facesContext.getExternalContext().getFlash();
flash.setKeepMessages(true);
facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "yourMessage", null));
return "namePage?faces-redirect=true";
```

**Into the namePage**

Change

```
<h:message globalsOnly="true" />
```

to

```
<h:messages globalsOnly="true" />
```