# How to display success message after redirection to another JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

After a customer is successfully added in my JSF application on the page `add_customer.jsf`, the user is redirected to the page `list_customers.jsf`.

On this page I would like a success message to be shown. The message should only be shown if the user is really coming from the `add_customer.jsf` page.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preserving-facesmessage-after-redirect-for-presentation-through-hmessage-in-j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137601/preserving-facesmessage-after-redirect-for-presentation-through-hmessage-in-j)         and look this question for detailed answer [adding-faces-message-to-redirected-page-using-externalcontext-redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595760/adding-faces-message-to-redirected-page-using-externalcontext-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add a message to The Flash in the action method that adds the customer.

You don't need to explicitly check that the user was coming from `add_customer.jsf`, if it's that page (or actually the code behind it) that sets the message. On the destination page you only need to have an `<h:messages>` component.

A co-worker of my posted an example CRUD app that does exactly this at: [Sample CRUD application with JSF](http://jdevelopment.nl/sample-crud-app-with-jsf-and-richfaces/).

The relevant code is in the backing bean [UserEdit](http://code.google.com/p/javaee6-crud-example/source/browse/src/backing/UserEdit.java?name=default) and the [page](http://code.google.com/p/javaee6-crud-example/source/browse/WebContent/index.xhtml?name=default) where the redirect happens to.

Note that if your JSF implementation is Mojarra, The Flash only works between pages in the same directory. If this bothers you, please consider voting for this issue: http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2136

Comment: i tried your method ,but it shows me the error : the method getFlash() is undefined for the type ExternalContext .

Comment: Are you really using JSF 2, or having JSF 2 on your build path?

Comment: I have jsf-api ,jsf-impl ,jstl ,standard on my build path

Comment: That sounds old. The current Mojarra impl. is one jar. To which AS do you deploy?

Comment: jsf2 implement Mojarra impl ,isn't it ? do you have a link to download Mojarra impl !

Comment: No, it's the other way around: Mojarra implements JSF 2. Do you know which AS (server) you are using? Since extended troubleshooting is discouraged in comments, you might want to start a new question about how to install/setup JSF and/or how to discover what you have running.

Comment: i'm using tomcat server 7 ,and i'm sorry for the troubleshooting ,because it's my first project with jsf !

Comment: You can download the latest JSF (Mojarra) release here: http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html goodluck!

Comment: @Arjan, you can still get the current version as separate jars from their maven [repo](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/com/sun/)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be using a [`<h:message>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/message.html) tag with which you could bind a message which can be populated before you redirect to `list_customer.jsf`.

We have been using this approach for showing messages in our application from last 3-4 years and occasionally used partial triggers to refresh on the same page.