# Get FacesContext in the xhtml page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have set a message in FacesContext as following

```
FacesContext facesContext = phaseEvent.getFacesContext();
facesContext.addMessage("lynasTest", ExceptionConverter.getFacesMessage(facesContext, cee, false));
```

now in the xhml page i want to see this message. I have tried following

```
<h:message for="lynasTest" />
<h:messages for="lynasTest" globalOnly="true" warnClass="color:orange" />
#{lynasTest}
```

its not showing my message. 
How to fix this??

Comment: We need more code. What do you do after setting the error? Redirecting o other page? Or is it an ajax call (are you updating the message components?)?

Comment: I am redirecting to another page

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preserving FacesMessage after redirect for presentation through <h:message> in JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137601/preserving-facesmessage-after-redirect-for-presentation-through-hmessage-in-j)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a h:input field

```
<h:inputText id="errorMessage" style="display: none"/>
<h:message  for="errorMessage"/>
```